# Can I change the ViewController that calls presentViewController?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller, orientation

I have a ViewController, VC1a, that presents VC2:

VC1a -> presentViewController: VC2

Is it possible to change VC1a into VC1b so that when dissmissViewControllerAnimated is called, it animates to VC1b instead of VC1a?

The reason I ask is because I want to return to a different screen without it animating back to VC1a. This relates to portrait/landscape changes.

Comment: I don't know why people have given this question negative ratings. Whats wrong with wanting to switch from a parent portrait view to a landscape parent view when you rotate a device in presented child viewcontroller??

Answer (score 0):

Warning. This is potentially a bad/confusing UI choice for your users. *But if you must...*

You may be able to put `VC1a` inside a `UINavigationController` and modify the navigation stack while `VC2` is in the foreground. Something like:

```
// in VC1a.m

[self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:^{
    NSMutableArray *navigationStack = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (UIViewController *viewController in self.navigationController.viewControllers)
    {
        if (viewController != self.navigationController.viewControllers.lastItem)
        {
            [navigationStack addObject:viewController];
        }
        else
        {
            VC1b *viewControllerToSwapIn = [[VC1b alloc] init];
            // probably some more initialization here
            [navigationStack addObject:viewControllerToSwapIn];
        }
    }
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = navigationStack;
}];
```

or possibly a better idea:

```
// in VC1a.m

[self presentViewController:VC2 animated:YES completion:^{
    VC1b *viewControllerToSwapIn = [[VC1b alloc] init];
    // probably some more initialization here
    [navigationStack addObject:viewControllerToSwapIn];

    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:viewControllerToSwapIn animated:NO];
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I implemented a Container view controller with two children - one for portrait, one for landscape and this took care of my problem.

I have spent days trying to figure out how to handle rotation correctly within iOS6 and I didn't realise there was a bug in rotating UITableViewController when pushed from a UINavigationController.

Thanks for the response @paulrehkugler - I was getting pretty desperate when I asked this question. There just doesn't seem to be any good examples of how to handle orientation changes while UINav/TableViewControllers are presented from a main view. I certainly wasn't wanting to implement such a hack.